# Proof the Similarity of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So let's say if $A$ is similar to $B$.
$B$ is also similar to $C$.
Then is $A$ also similar to $C$? I think so.

By the definition of matrix similarity, two $n$ by $n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar if $B = P^{-1}AP$. Which means the matrix is also diagnolizable.

if $B = P^{-1}AP$, then $C = Q^{-1} B Q = Q^{-1} P^{-1}APQ$

How should I go on to prove it?

Comment: Hey thanks! That's what I got! I was just hestiant in writing P-1Q-1 as another variable. But yea if that's ok then it's all good. Just wondering how did you write out the mathematical notation?

Comment: For mathematical notation we use LaTeX here, basically you write a formula between \$ A \$ which gives you $A$, for more read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange

Answer (score 4):

Let $B= P^{-1}AP$ and $C=Q^{-1}BQ$ for some invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$, then

$$ C = Q^{-1}P^{-1}APQ = (PQ)^{-1}APQ = R^{-1}AR, $$

where $R=PQ$ is an invertible matrix since $R^{-1}= Q^{-1}P^{-1}$. Thus $A$ and $C$ are similar.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, they are similar. You even provided proof that $A$ is similar to $C$ when you did this:

$$B = P^{-1} A P \implies C = Q^{-1} B Q = Q^{-1} (P^{-1} A P) Q = (PQ)^{-1} A (PQ).$$

I do not think it follows that they are diagonalizable. What you do have is that they have the same eigenvalues, but you cannot say much otherwise.